# How to delete a docker image?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-desktop

My project includes a Dockerfile to build an image. I've made modifications to that Dockerfile and want to see if it works. So i closed my program and listed all docker images in powershell using `docker image ls -a`. I deletetd all unused images using `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)` and `docker image prune -a`.

But my image keeps **not** getting deleted, but simply 'untagged':

```
Untagged: my_image:latest
Untagged: my_image@sha256:16eb92a476be0...
```

All containers are stopped and deleted before trying to remove the image.
When i restart my application to build a new image, the old one keeps getting used:

```
> docker image ls -a
REPOSITORY                     TAG           IMAGE ID            CREATED      
/my_image                      latest        0d79904a74b0        2 months ago
```

How do i actually physically remove the old image so my application can build a new one?

Comment: Does `docker ps -a` show a container running the image?  How are you restarting the application (you must delete and recreate the container to make it use a different or newer image)?

Comment: Before trying to remove the image  ```docker ps -a``` lists no containers and docker desktop tells me "No containers running". My program uses Kubernetes to instantiate the containers it needs and deletes all containers, pods and namespaces when closed.

Comment: There's no need to delete the old one, just build the new one. Show your steps and output from building the new image.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

At first, you need to delete/stop the running container that is using your image(which one you want to remove).

- `docker ps -a`: To see all the running containers in your machine.
- `docker stop <container_id>`: To stop a running container.
- `docker rm <container_id>`: To remove/delete a docker container(only if it stopped).
- `docker image ls`: To see the list of all the available images with their tag, image id, creation time and size.
- `docker rmi <image_id>`: To delete a specific image.
- `docker rmi -f <image_id>`: To delete a docker image forcefully
- `docker rm -f (docker ps -a | awk '{print$1}')`: To delete all the docker container available in your machine
- `docker image rm <image_name>`: To delete a specific image

To remove the image, you have to remove/stop all the containers which are using it.

- `docker system prune -a`: To clean the docker environment, removing all the containers and images.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I forgot to include in my original question that the container is stopped. ```docker ps -a``` lists no containers and docker desktop tells me "No containers running". Still, The image keeps getting untagged instead of deleted. Trying to delete all untagged images using ```docker rmi $(docker images -f “dangling=true” -q)``` results in nothing happening.  
I found [this](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-remove-none-images-after-building/7050/18) explaining why docker untags images, but i do not know how to fix it.

Comment: @tdragojevic `delete rmi -f <image_id>` can you try this command to delete a docker image forcefully

Comment: @tdragojevic Have you tried to use `docker image prune` or `docker rmi $(docker images | awk '/^<none>/ {print $3}')` to delete untagged images ?

Comment: @SahadatHossain `delete rmi -f <image_id>` should be `docker rmi -f <image_id>`